# My Schema is not the same as my Database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, schema

i'm new using Php Cake. I'm using version 1.3. width Mysql. So I had been making some modifications in a web system. So, i had added a new column in one of the tables, and when i try to save i had noticed the column didn't appear in the schema. So i had run the console command "cake schema generate" but in the schema.php generated file i don't see the column i had added in the database, so i think that's the reason why was not saving. So... How could i do to update this Schema... ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the new column in your schema.php.

If you now want to build tables from this schema.php

To later rebuild the database schema from your previously made schema.php file run:

```
$ Console/cake schema create
```

This will drop and create the tables based on the contents of the schema.php.

[schema-management](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html)

Edit :
try it with the `-f` option.

```
cake schema generate -f
```

Note :

The schema shell will only process tables for which there are models defined. To force the schema shell to process all the tables, you must add the -f option in the command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I think i was not clear. I had change the database without cake(i mean using alter table...) So how i could do to update FROM the DATABASE the current structure to cake php schema? Thank you...

Comment: I don't want to erase the database and re create the tables from the cake schema... i want to update that schema.php from the database. It is possible?